# Rails :order, can I order by 2 things at the same time, one before the other?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

so I want to do something like this:

```
, :order => "(products.name = 'Some Product' or products.name) desc", :order=>'distance'
```

has anyone done this before? I realize that I cant do it the way I have written, but hope it explains the order I want the orders to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.

```
:order => "column1 ASC, column2 DESC"
```

Comment: I did this
:order => "(products.name = 'Some Product' or products.name) desc, distance"
very similar to what you suggested